# Eclipse PHP (PDT): App::make(Filesystem::class) = Syntax Error unexpected class

Tags: php, eclipse, class, compiler-errors, eclipse-pdt

I use the following Statement quite a lot:

```
App::make(Filesystem::class)
```

and Eclipse PHP-Edition (PDT) underlines the `class` with red and marks this as an Error (on the left border): "`Syntax Error, unexcpected class"`.

How can I fix this, that this is either eignored or even better, correctly recognized as correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project (or entire workspace), have interpreter set to PHP < 5.5.

For PHP >= 5.5 everything is ok on current snapshot (will be released in next week). See also PDT help: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.php.help/html/reference/preferences/php_interpreter.html

If error still exist you should report bug on PDT bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: thanks a million times! Great helpfull answer! Wish you all the best. thanks!